# Podfile usage for iOS apps

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cocoapods

I'm very new to using podfiles and have a bit of confusion around how they work and what I need to do to use them. I have followed the 'Getting Started' section on the main website and have successfully created a podfile and run install to pull in the dependencies. The questions I have are as follows:

1. I see a new section in my project which appears to list the pods i've requested, however they all seem to be in red - is that normal? If not what have I done wrong / what do I need to do?

[image]

2. In terms of some of the Core iOS frameworks (e.g. UIKit, Foundation, etc.) do I still need to manually import them as frameworks into my project? Can I add them to my podfile so I can manage everything in a single place? If so how (does the syntax vary/differ?)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. They appear as red because this frameworks not built yet. After you build project they should look normal.
2. Yes, CocoaPods only handle third-party dependencies.